# XMPP packet data maximum limitation with using open fire server in iOS

Tags: ios, openfire, xmppframework

I am currently working on chat application in iOS. For that I use XMPP and OpenFire server.

My questions are:

- What is maximum packet data size we can send through chat message?
- Is there any server side (OpenFire) setting require to limit max chat message size?

Answer (score 1):

From the code, it seems to be one MB

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/6cc1e42df094fa36c94968745409921022bff6cf/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/nio/XMLLightweightParser.java, line 110

```
// Set default max buffer size to 1MB. If limit is reached then close connection
maxBufferSize = JiveGlobals.getIntProperty(MAX_PROPERTY_NAME, 1048576);
```